Delta star transformation/ find branch current
what is the best way to determine the current i3 and i6 in this circuit? I tried to do a star-delta transformation. Unfortunately, I "lost" the current i3. The values ​​can be seen in the picture.
Late addition: There's a special limitation. Equations which contain more than one unknown are not allowed. Every equation to be solved can have only one unknown.
Many thanks in advance


My best way is to use a simulator.

Yes, I already did :)

You should put the simulation result into your question.

Make a Thevenin equivalent when R6 is considered to be the detached load. Calculate with it I6. Deriving Thevenin equivalent is straightforward, you do not need to solve any equations.
Knowing I6 and the 1 ampere coming through R2 give I5, the current of R5. Now you have 2 ways to write the voltage over R6. It's (I6)(R6).
The voltage over R6 is as well (I3)(R3) + (I5)*(R5). Now you have only a single equation with a single unknown I3.

Delta-Star (sometimes known as Wye-Delta) transformation might be only useful if you're dealing with a 3-phase system (in my opinion). I would probably do mesh current analysis where you would draw your loops.
Doing this will give you a set of linear equations to solve. The good news is that one of loops will contain a 1A source, so now you only have two unknowns: i3 and i6. You have three equations and two unknowns.

Thank you very much. According to the task, I have to solve it without a system of equations

@Omar This is new information you have presented to us. In that case, you'll have to do some simplification of which resistors are in parallel or in series.

problem conditions

According to the task, I have to solve it without a system of
equations

Good enough. Let's do it without solving a simultaneous system of equations.
I will also avoid \$\Delta\leftrightarrows\$ Y conversions. They simply aren't worth the weight of memorizing their formulas. And they aren't actually needed. I haven't used them in 30 years' time.
redraw (always redraw -- just get in the practice of it)
This is what you have:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
But you don't care at all about \$R_2\$. It has no impact whatsoever on the current reaching node \$V_x\$ and its existence only impacts the voltage difference across the current source. So the circuit you care about is:

simulate this circuit
Thevenize
Thevenize the left and right sides. (I must assume you can do that much.):

simulate this circuit
The difference, \$\frac13-\frac14=\frac1{12}\$, tells you that the current through \$R_3\$ is \$\frac1{12}\$th of \$V_x\$ divided by the sum of these three resistances, or it must be the case that \$I_3=\frac{V_x}{410\:\Omega}\$. But this current also flows through \$R_{_{\text{TH}_1}}\$ and \$R_{_{\text{TH}_2}}\$, as well.
solve for voltages
So the voltage drop across \$R_{_{\text{TH}_1}}\$ must be \$\frac2{123}\,V_x\$ and the voltage drop across \$R_{_{\text{TH}_2}}\$ must be \$\frac3{164}\,V_x\$, as shown above.
Therefore: \$V_y=\frac13\,V_x-\frac2{123}\,V_x=\frac{13}{41}\,V_x\$.
Therefore: \$V_z=\frac14\,V_x+\frac3{164}\,V_x=\frac{11}{41}\,V_x\$.
Therefore: \$\frac{V_x-\frac{13}{41}\,V_x}{R_6}+\frac{V_x-\frac{11}{41}\,V_x}{R_5}=\frac{V_y}{R_1}+\frac{V_z}{R_4}=1\:\text{A}\$.
Therefore: \$V_x=\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}\$.
This is all just straight-forward calcs and no need for solving a simultaneous system of equations.
It's just a sequence of logic and the use of algebra and only one variable. That's it.
solve for currents
You should now have no problems at all working out any and all branch currents. Keep in mind that \$V_x=\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}\$.
Start with \$I_3\$ because we already set up an equation for it.

\$I_3=\frac{\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}}{410\:\Omega}=\frac1{24}\:\text{A}\approx 41.67\:\text{mA}\$
\$I_1=\frac{\frac{13}{41}\,\cdot\,\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}}{10\:\Omega}=\frac{13}{24}\:\text{A}\approx 541.67\:\text{mA}\$
\$I_4=\frac{\frac{11}{41}\,\cdot\,\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}}{10\:\Omega}=\frac{11}{24}\:\text{A}\approx 458.33\:\text{mA}\$
\$I_6=\frac{\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}\:-\:\frac{13}{41}\,\cdot\,\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}}{20\:\Omega}=\frac{7}{12}\:\text{A}\approx 583.33\:\text{mA}\$
\$I_5=\frac{\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}\:-\:\frac{11}{41}\,\cdot\,\frac{205}{12}\:\text{V}}{30\:\Omega}=\frac{5}{12}\:\text{A}\approx 416.67\:\text{mA}\$

I had better not need to tell you the current in \$R_2\$.
You can double-check. You should find that \$I_1+I_4=I_5+I_6=1\:\text{A}\$, for example.
summary
Using simultaneous systems of linear equations with a solver is very convenient. But as I earlier pointed out here, there are many ways to do things. And it's important that you develop a large set of mental tools to work with.
(Especially if you find yourself someday on a desert island, with only a stick and some sand to work with, and want to bide away the time solving problems like this.)
